# What is the phonetical link between pacman's "--refresh" and "-y" options?

Tags: pacman

In pacman, `--refresh` and `-y` are the same option. But how are they phonetical related to each other? Is there a mnemonic?

For comparison: for many binaries `-f` is the short option of `--force`. It should be obvious how "f" is derived from "force" :)

Answer (score 4):

There are said to be [two hard problems in computer science](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096?lang=en). One of those is naming things. This is an effect of that.

The database syncing feature was originally added as a separate `pacsync` command in 1.23. This command was then merged into `pacman` in the 2.0 release, and `pacman` gained many new options, including `--sync`/`-S`. Internally, this was still handled in a `pacsync.c`, and the action of refreshing the database was called syncing (the `sync` subcommand of the old `pacsync`, the `sync_synctree()` function in the new `pacsync.c`). Now we already have a master `--sync` option, so what do we do with the sub-option to that which syncs databases? I speculate that:

- the devs decided to call it `--refresh` as a long option, a reasonable name,
- but otherwise honour the sync-named things in the code by thinking of it as a second `--sync` option, because those things *are* sensibly named
- and therefore, as is usually done when two long options have the same first character, moved to the second character for the short option, `-y`.

As a factor in favour of this, the combination would become `-Sy`, the first two letters of "sync'.

Part of the code for option handling:

```c
while((opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, "ARUQSTYr:vhscVfnoldpiuy", opts, &option_index))) {
    if(opt < 0) {
        break;
    }
    switch(opt) {
...
        case 'y': pmo_s_sync = 1; break;
```

This whole thing happened ~15 years ago (2002), and I couldn't find any online discussions about in my searching, but I'm confident this is what happened.

Comment: Hi @muru, thank you for refining my question and giving a reasonable answer. I like the answer very much, especially because you gave me a mnemonic for `-Sy`(nc)